# Error using tree-view component in ng-Zorro, version 13.0

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFCV5.png)

Error using tree-view component in ng-Zorro, version 13.0,
If nzTreeControl or nzDataSource cannot find this property, the tree-view cannot be used

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't share your code in images, to make it easier to help you and follow the guidelines, please review this article to see why this is important [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the module of the *zorro component* you want to use (NzTreeModule in your case) in your own main module?

From the [**ngZorro Official Doc**](https://ng-zorro.gitee.io/docs/getting-started/en):
you need to import the component modules that you want to use into the app.module.ts file and feature modules.

Taking the following NzButtonModule module as an example, first import the component module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NzButtonModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/button';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NzButtonModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then use the component inside the template:

```
<button nz-button nzType="primary">Primary</button>
```

Comment: The tree View module is already imported into the main module. All tree View parameters are available in the main module, except nzTreeControl and nzDataSource